# EXC_BREAKPOINT from -[FIRUser parseIDToken:error:]

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm using firebase ios-sdk to handle authentication in the app that I'm currently working on, but sometimes I get a crash when I call `Auth.auth().currentUser.getIDToken()`

This doesn't happens all the time and not with all the users, actually with just one user.

Does anyone has an idea why this is happening?

Cheers

Comment: _Does anyone has an idea why this is happening?_ - probably not, considering you didn't include any actual details of the issue, like any relevant code

Comment: Related to https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/1208 ?

Comment: @mag_zbc `Auth.auth().currentUser.getIDToken()` this is the code. After the user is authenticated, i call that and for some users with certain devices, it crashes.